# Inner join in my doctrine2 query increases execution time from 400 milliseconds to 5 secs

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm

Inner join in my doctrine2 query increases execution time from 400 milliseconds to 5 secs, but if I extract SQL and run directly in SQLSERVER studio it takes few milliseconds to execute.

below is my query, the bottle neck is inner join only:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$q = $qb->select( 'wp.id, wp.last_activity_datetime' )
->from( '\Entities\wall_post', 'wp' )
->LeftJoin( 'wp.wall_postsLikes', 'likes' )
->LeftJoin( 'wp.wall_postsShare', 'shares' )
->LeftJoin( 'wp.wall_postsComment', 'comments' )
->leftJoin( 'wp.wall_postsFrom_user','fromUser');
if( $wall_type == self::WALL_TYPE_SOCIALISE )
{
    $q->leftJoin( 'wp.wall_postsSocialise_album','album');
    $q->innerJoin( 'album.socialise_albumsSocialise_photo','photo');
}
$q->setParameter( 'my_links_r', $my_links_r )
->setParameter( 1, $userId )

->setFirstResult( $offset )
->setMaxResults( $limit )
->groupBy( 'wp.id, wp.last_activity_datetime' )
->orderBy( 'wp.last_activity_datetime', 'DESC' );

if( $wall_type )
{
    $q->where( 'wp.wall_postsFrom_user = ?1 AND wp.wall_type = ?4' );
    $q->orWhere( 'wp.wall_postsFrom_user IN (:my_links_r) AND wp.wall_type = ?4' );
    $q->orWhere( 'likes.likesLiked_by IN (:my_links_r) AND wp.wall_type = ?4' );
    $q->orWhere( 'shares.sharesShared_by IN (:my_links_r) AND wp.wall_type = ?4' );
    $q->orWhere( 'comments.commentsIlook_user IN (:my_links_r) AND wp.wall_type = ?4' );
    $q->andWhere('fromUser.account_closed_on is null');
    if( $blocked_user_ids_arr ):
        $q->setParameter( 'blocked_users_r', $blocked_user_ids_arr );
        $q->andWhere( 'wp.wall_postsFrom_user NOT IN (:blocked_users_r)' );
    endif;

    $q->setParameter( 4, $wall_type );
}


$q = $q->getQuery()->getResult( \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY );
```

Following is my SQL extract, it runs fantastic with inner join also:

```
SELECT TOP 10 w0_.id AS id0, w0_.last_activity_datetime AS last_activity_datetime1
FROM wall_post w0_
  LEFT JOIN likes l1_ ON  w0_.id = l1_.wall_post_id
  LEFT JOIN share s2_ ON w0_.id = s2_.wall_post_id
  LEFT JOIN comments c3_ ON w0_.id = c3_.wall_post_id 
  LEFT JOIN ilook_user i4_ ON w0_.from_user_id = i4_.id 
  LEFT JOIN socialise_album s5_ ON w0_.socialise_album_id = s5_.id 
  INNER JOIN socialise_photo s6_ ON s5_.id = s6_.socialise_album_id 
WHERE ((w0_.from_user_id = 1 AND w0_.wall_type = 2) 
   OR (w0_.from_user_id IN (1) AND w0_.wall_type = 2)  
   OR (s2_.ilook_user_id IN (1) AND w0_.wall_type = 2)) 
  AND i4_.account_closed_on IS NULL 
GROUP BY w0_.id, w0_.last_activity_datetime 
ORDER BY w0_.last_activity_datetime DESC
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you 100% sure that your above code is generating the exact same sql as the sql in the bottom? Also what kind of fields does your album.socialise... table have?

Comment: @JeremyC. Yes SQL is extracted from the above doctrine query only. My socialise_photo table have 1 primary key(int), 2 other integer fields and 4 varchar and 1 datetime field.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exact answer but solves my purpose if I use **having statement** and **left join** in stead of **inner join**:

```
$q->leftJoin( 'album.socialise_albumsSocialise_photo','photo');
$q->having('count(photo) > 1');
```

Comment: Still in doubt that why doctrine2 inner join was taking 10x more time.